# Image inside flex item ignoring max-width

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm just starting with flex layout and encounter one problem. I have the following code:

```css
        wrapper  {display: flex; width: 100%; }
        graphic  {flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; text-align: center;}
        graphic img {width: 100%; max-width: 400px;}
        nav      {width: 200px;}
```

```html
    <wrapper>
        <nav><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" /></nav>
        <graphic><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" /></graphic>
        <nav><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" /></nav>
    </wrapper>
```

Left and right are fixed width; center grows and shrinks when resizing the browser window - OK so far. However I would like to prevent the center image from exceeding it's natural size. I expected that max-width would do the job but it doesn't. Can you explain why and how to do in a correct way?
My browser is Opera. PS: Sorry for the selfmade tags, I got this code from another forum and didn't correct it yet.

Comment: So sorry, so silly error: The natural width of the image is 200px, not 400px! The code works fine! https://jsfiddle.net/Sempervivum/d9895ocv/3/

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code it looks like the `max-width: 400px` should be applied to the parent element of the image, in this case `<graphic>` this will prevent the image container from being larger than 400px.

```
graphic  {
  flex-grow: 1; 
  flex-shrink: 1; 
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center; 
}
graphic img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Changed this in my fiddle but the result is the same:
https://jsfiddle.net/Sempervivum/d9895ocv/2/

Comment: @Sempervivum Strange it works in Chrome and it should be supported in Opera. Do you mind posting a screenshot of the behavior?

Comment: See my comment for my initial posting. Code works fine, I made a mistake when  defining the natural width.